# Send One of Three Email Templates From Form Input

Tags: php, html, email

I have a form which is just name, email and option select. Based on one of three options, I want to send a different email to the email address provided, and also address the name in the email template. I know simple php mailers but I'm not sure where to start with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm reading, you are wanting to have a html form which gets a users name and e-mail address, and then a option list to categorize the response to the form.

to do this I would have the action of the form point to a php file that would check for a name, valid e-mail, and then see which option was selected.

I would then use a switch/case in php to identify which option was selected in the option field, and build a variable with the e-mail you wish to send.

Then at the end of the php, if everything checks out, I would then send the variable as the e-mail.

example:

html form, name field as 'name', email field as 'email' and option field as 'option' returning numbers representing the options.

`if (checkforinputs()=true){ // if valid inputs continue with code.
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $option=$_POST['option'];
        switch $option{
            case: '1'
                $emailmessage="Hello ".@name.": Message One";
                break;
            case: '2'
                $emailmessage="Hello ".@name.": Message Two";
                break;
            default:
                $emailmessage="This should never be acted, only valid options should be passed"
                break;
        }
        sendemailfunction($emailmessage);
    }
    function checkforinputs(){
        //code here to check inputs from form to validate
    }
    function sendemailfunction($email){
        //Code to send email
    }`

Comment: Yes!! this is awesome thanks dude! How would I send a different email emplate, like html file for each option?

Comment: put the html into the $emailmessage variables.